# Setting value for nullboolean field in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working in Django and accepting value for a nullBoolean field. I am able to get the value but not able to store it correctly in the model. My model is

```
group_member=models.NullBooleanField(blank=False)
```

form for the same is

```
CHOICES=[(True, 'Yes'),(False,'No')]
group_member=forms.ChoiceField(
    label='Member of a group', 
    choices=CHOICES, 
    widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
    help_text='Help text')
```

Then I get a response through reading the form on 'POST' as

```
        answer=form.cleaned_data['group_member']
```

and then I store the choice in a new record at the time of its creation

```
        group_info=group.objects.create(
                mem_id=mem_id,
                group_member=answer
                )
```

I am always getting 'Yes' saved as response even though the choice has been 'No' which I presume is changed from 'unknown' which should be the value at the time new record is generated. I tried replacing answer with 'No' but also does not work. Changing the value later (not at the time of creation of record ) also does not seem to work. Where am I making the mistake.

Comment: Why are you using `NullBooleanField` and not regular `BooleanField`? You don't seem to use `NULL` anywhere.

Comment: Documentation states (about `choices`): Either an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field, or a callable that returns such an iterable. This argument accepts **the same formats** as the choices argument to a model field.

Your choices don't have _Unknown_, so maybe that's the case.

Comment: Siegmeyer since I will be reading the values later, I need to know if the value was set or in initial state. Therefore unknown represents initial state and required.

Comment: And I added  the 3rd option as well with no difference. answer is getting the value as False but storing yes instead.